# Oracle SQL - Naming a case column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select site,
case
when site='AppCircle' then (count(create_dtime)*0.4438083264)
when site='AppCircle Clips' then (count(create_dtime)*0.0096978792)
when site='BC : SponsorPay' then (count(create_dtime)*0.9620989399)
when site='BonusCoins.com : Aarki' then (count(create_dtime)*0.4612565445)
when site='Nielsen Rewards' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.6000000000)
when site ='Portal : Paymentwall' then (count(create_dtime)*0.5433541667)
when site ='Portal : RadiumOne' then (count(create_dtime)*0.0619798753)
when site ='Portal : TrialPay' then (count(create_dtime)*2.1468159204)
when site ='bonuscp_login' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.1500000000)
when site ='facebook_like' then (count(create_dtime)*2.1468159204)
when site ='iTunes' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.0300000000)
end
From player_aux_pt
Where
Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(Create_Dtime) <= To_Date('2012-Nov-30','yyyy-mon-dd')  
group by site
```

which results in two columns of data

```
Site    [insert every case statement here]
```

I just want that second column of information to be named "Profit"

```
Site    Profit
```

I have tried many different ways an am stuck.

Comment: The searched case syntax you're using would be better as a simple case, with "CASE SITE WHEN 'AppCircle' then ... WHEN 'AppCircle Clips' then ...". Actually it would be better to place the site values and the constants into another table and just join to it. The TRUNC on the Create_Dtime column is not good practice -- better to remove it and replace "<= To_Date('2012-Nov-30' ..." with "< To_Date('2012-Dec-01'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Since your CASE statement is just a basic [DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) pattern, check the link for a concise alternative.

```
select site,
       count(create_dtime)
     * DECODE(site, 'AppCircle', 0.4438083264,
                    'AppCircle Clips', 0.0096978792,
                    'BC : SponsorPay', 0.9620989399,
                    ......) Profit
 ....
```

---

You can alias columns by giving it a name after the expression or base column name, e.g.

```
SELECT
    Site,
    Site ReNamedSite,
    Concat(Site,'a') "AddedAnA",
    COALESCE(Site,Address) AS "Two Words"
...
```

Notes:

1. The keyword `AS` is optional
2. Usage of double quotes is optional, unless you use multiple words

i.e.

```
select site,
case
when site='AppCircle' then (count(create_dtime)*0.4438083264)
when site='AppCircle Clips' then (count(create_dtime)*0.0096978792)
when site='BC : SponsorPay' then (count(create_dtime)*0.9620989399)
when site='BonusCoins.com : Aarki' then (count(create_dtime)*0.4612565445)
when site='Nielsen Rewards' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.6000000000)
when site ='Portal : Paymentwall' then (count(create_dtime)*0.5433541667)
when site ='Portal : RadiumOne' then (count(create_dtime)*0.0619798753)
when site ='Portal : TrialPay' then (count(create_dtime)*2.1468159204)
when site ='bonuscp_login' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.1500000000)
when site ='facebook_like' then (count(create_dtime)*2.1468159204)
when site ='iTunes' then (count(create_dtime)*-0.0300000000)
end Profit
From player_aux_pt
Where
Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Nov-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(Create_Dtime) <= To_Date('2012-Nov-30','yyyy-mon-dd')  
group by site
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rename (or name) columns and expressions in SQL using AS:

```
CASE 
  WHEN. . .
  WHEN. . .
END AS Profit
```

However, using a CASE expression in that way is not very extensible.  Consider moving the multiplication factor to another table, keyed on `site` and then JOINing that table into the query.